# Azure ACS and Google as an Identity Provider

Tags: azure, google-api, acs

I was relying on Azure ACS to offer users the possibility of logging in using, among other providers, their Google accounts.

As I was registering a new Azure ACS namespace I stumbled upon the message that "Google has closed OpenID 2.0 registrations and this feature is deprecated".

Is there another way to use Google as an identity provider in new ACS namespaces? Work-arounds?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow, but it looks like it is possible to support multiple identity providers without ACS: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services

Comment: Hey did you find an option?, I am stuck in the same problem!! thanks!

Comment: Hi, I'm still trying to get a solution working but it involves using OWIN middleware. I'm already able to authenticate the user with the provider however so far I wasn't able to update the Request's current user. The current principal keeps being set to a Generic Principal even though I set it to a ClaimsPrincipal through a custom OWIN Middleware "step". I'll update this post as soon as I have a solution working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up replacing ACS by a solution similar to the one described [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services).
The drawback is that if you are relying on ACS for claims transformation you'll have to implement it yourself.